# JavaScript Program to find ocurrence of charcter in the given string

Tags: javascript

I have run this function successfully but I don't understand what it does. Could it be explained to me?

```js
function char_frequency(str) {
  var count = {};
  str.split('').forEach(function(s) {
    count[s] = count[s] ? count[s] + 1 : 1;
  });
  console.log(count);
}
char_frequency("aaahhabbjkjjkkl");
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick interpretation, this function is calling somewhere and takes in a string (str) as its parameter, then declares a local variable called count that holds an array of char_frequencies. After it splits each character with a split("") and for each one is then passed with a function variable (s). count[s] <== is changing # for each character inside of the string and returns each one, repeats for each character and returns the strings that repeats per run.

```js
    function char_frequency(str){ // Function to call and pass a (string) as (str)
      var count = {}; // Array to hold characters
      str.split('').forEach(function(s) { // Split each character and for each one do something.
        count[s] = count[s] ? count[s]+1 : 1;}); // Add to count array each one with [s] being an increasing value.
        console.log(count); // Log to console
    }
    char_frequency("aaahhabbjkjjkkl"); // Calling of the function
    char_frequency("Print the amount of times each character repeats");
```

Answer (score 0):

`aaahhabbjkjjkkl` is the parameter for `char_frequency()`.
`str.split('')` do the task of seperating each character and each character is the parameter for anonymous function.
 If there was any occurence of the parameter character in past, increase the counter by one, otherwise set counter to 1.

At the last of the loop, you will have the occurance of each character in count.

Answer (score 0):

It will give you the occurrence of the particular character.

```js
function char_frequency(str){
  var count = {};
  str.split('').forEach(function(s) {
    count[s] = count[s] ? count[s]+1 : 1;});
    console.log(count);
}
char_frequency("aaahhabbjkjjkkl");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in this function your are making a map of frequency of a character  in the string.

Lets break your function step by step :

> str.split('') => it will split the passed string and return an array
>   of characters.
>
> Example :  var str = "abcd";
>              var arr = str.split(''); // arr will be [a,b,c,d]

After that you simply iterate over this array of character using `forEach()` And then forEach character, you check whether it exist in your map or not if it is present in the map you simply increase its count to one if it not present than it to map and set its value as 1.

```
 count[s] = count[s] ? count[s]+1 : 1;}); // this line checks whether the character is present in the map or not if it is not present than add it to map and set count as 1, if present than increase count.
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here, you know what it does.

But are really asking how it does it?

Below I've placed comments on each line to hopefully explain it.

```
function char_frequency(str){      //create a function called char_frequency
   var count = {};                 //store our counts here
   str.split('').                  //lets split our string into an array
      forEach(function(s)          //now for each character
      {
      count[s] = count[s]          //set count for our character
         ? count[s]+1              //if count exists add 1 to it
         : 1;                      //if it doesn't set it to 1
      });
   console.log(count);             //show result in console
}

char_frequency("aaahhabbjkjjkkl"); //run our created function
```